# Fixed my memory leak and I don't understand why it worked

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I used the CRT tool to find memory leaks in my code, and when I found I fixed one thing and it took care of the memory leaks, but I can't understand what happened there.

My original code was:

```
while (getline(inf, line))
{
    Video vid = *deserialize_video(line);
    Video_dict[vid.get_name()] = vid;

}
```

where deserialize_video is a function that get a string as an input and return a pointer to a new object created in that function, vid type.
What I am trying to say is this the function ends  with  :

> return new Video(name,year,type,price,length,genre);

After a few tries I ended up with this code:

```
while (getline(inf, line))
{
    Video * vid = deseriallize_video(line);
    Video_dict[vid->get_name()] = *vid;
    delete vid;

}
```

And it solved my memory leaks. The problem is I can't understand how many duplicates were created in the 1st, and why was the 1st code wrong if the deserialize... function sends back a pointer.

Comment: Well when you call a function and it returns a pointer _and_ gives you ownership of that pointer it's up do _you_ to delete it. Since you weren't deleting it you ended up with a memory leak.

Comment: We know nothing of `Video` or `Video_dict` or `deserialize_video()`, but I can take a wild guess that not deleting an allocated object is what caused memory leak.

Comment: the difference between the two code snippets is that the second sets an index of an array to data stored at an address value where as the first sets an index of an array to the actual address value itself.

Comment: Maybe investigate what `delete` does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> deseriallize_video is a fucntion that get a string as an input and return a pointer to a new object created in that function

Well, there you go!

That object was dynamically allocated with `new`, and must later be de-allocated with `delete`.

It's as simple as that.

---

You made several copies of the object in your example.

Here, the object (after the pointer is dereferenced) is used to copy-initialise a new `Video` named `vid`:

```
Video vid = *deseriallize_video(line);
```

And here, presuming `Video_dict` is a standard container or equivalent to one, `vid` is copied into it:

```
Video_dict[vid.get_name()] = vid;
```

*(BTW you typo'd that to `*vid` in your second example.)*

---

We don't know enough (read: anything) about `Video` to categorically state improvements, but it's likely that you want to drop the dynamic allocation and pointers entirely. Return by value if you can. Define meaningful move constructors if you must.

Comment: thank you for your help .
I didn't want to add more of the code because I was afriad I would struggle to much to explain what I did / tried to do , that the question wont be clear.
I tried what you suggested and changed to fucntion to return by value 
> return Video(name,year,type,price,length,genre);
and now the code is :



       Video vid = deseriallize_video(line);
  Video_dict[vid.get_name()] = vid;

is it more correct this way?

Comment: @maor: What I said before about not being able to state anything categorically without knowing what `Video` does ... has not magically changed just because you gave a reason for not explaining what `Video` does.